# Making a field `Final` in an Immutable class?

Tags: java, immutability

Recently I attended an interview.

I was asked how you can make a class `Immutable`.

I told him the answer.

But then he asked me why the fields are `final`?

I answered so that the user doesn't accidentally change the value of the field and it will give compiler error if he does so.

Now he ask me there is a `immutable` class with only getter methods.

Then in this class what is the use of `final`?

I was not able to answer. He told there is a reason behind that.

Can somebody explain?

Comment: Using final will avoid mutating the state within this class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Effective Java:

**Make all fields final.** This clearly expresses your intent in a manner that is enforced by the system. Also, it is necessary to ensure correct behavior if a reference to a newly created instance is passed from one thread to another without synchronization, as spelled out in the memory model.

Comment: To clarify, `final` guarantees a field is fully initialized before the constructor finishes.  The compiler can re-order the operations inside of the constructor and they can take place after the object reference is created and the constructor finishes

Comment: @Nick Can you please clarify by some code? I am not able to understand.

Comment: @Thinker it can't really clarified by code.  Here's the important bit in the Java spec - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

Comment: @Thinker for a detailed but approachable explanation, you should look up Java Concurrency In Practice. It's to do with the Java Memory Model and the ways in which compilers are allowed to optimise and reorder instructions. The `final` keyword is used to guarantee that the field is fully initialised and visible when passed to another thread.

Answer (score 2):

> Now he ask me there is a immutable class with only getter methods.
>
> Then in this class what is the use of final?

Only getter methods do not ensure that a class is immutable. If you expose the internal state than a client can change the class's state.

Immutable means that you can not change an objects state once it is created.

Making all fields final and providing only getters will not make it immutable out of the box. Imagine the following code:

```
public class MyString {
    private final char[] content;

    public MyString(String str){
         this.content = str.toCharArray();
    }

    public char[] getContent(){
        return this.content; // internal state exposed. You should return a copy.
    }
}
```

This class has only final fields and only getter methods but is still mutable. Imagine this client code:

```
MyString myString = new MyString("test");
myString.getContent()[0] = 'f';
```

> Now he ask me there is a immutable class with only getter methods.
>
> Then in this class what is the use of final?

The use of final is to express your intention with java's language features and therefore enforce them by the compiler.

So making a variable final is good for primitive types, but you must take care if the variable is a reference. In this case you must either ensure that

- the object you are referencing is also immutable or
- only your instance has access to that object.

The later can only be ensured by the programmer. So take extra care when you return references.

Comment: You still didn't answer why `final` is necessary, though.

Comment: In a correctly programmed immutable class it does not really have any meaning. What it does for the programmer is that it communicates intent. Which is also sort of redundant, since a properly programmed immutable class documents it's immutability without any ambiguity. But since the JVM does not read the javadocs it does help the JVM optimize the code (a reference to a final field can be shared since it is known to never change).

Comment: @Torben declaring a field `final` does have meaning, see @JakubHr's answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, immutability is of course achieved in the way that an object is used, rather than by enforcement. You could always change a final field's value with Reflection.

The *use* of it is to allow the compiler to prevent you from breaking immutability, as well as to denote the need for immutability (such as when you use an inner class that uses a method-local reference).

Answer (score -1):

'final' as the keyword's name suggest means that the attribute to which final keyword is attached can't be changed(in terms of value) in other words it behaves like a constant.if fields are not 'final' then inside local method you can change the value of fields.

Comment: In Java a "constant" means a value that can not be changed during program execution. A final field does not qualify as constant as it's value is assigned during run time. Thus it should be described as a field that can not be changed once it has been initialized.

Comment: Sorry -1, this answer doesn't add anything to what the question already states